# how to get data from servlet to ajax and using in JSP page

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets

```
window.onload = function() {
    alert("This is a onload function ...");
    var pass = window.dialogArguments; 
    var fields = pass.split(/~/);
    var userID = fields[0];
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        dataType: "JSON",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: "/HostingProject/AdminCustServlet",
        data: {ActionType:"1",userID:userID},
        success: function(data ,textStatus, jqXHR){
        var splitString = data.split('|');
        $.each(splitString, function(i, item) {
        var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + item.AccountNumber + "</td>" + "<td>" +          item.AccountType + "</td>" + "<td>" + item.AccountStatus + "</td>" + "</tr>";
   $(tblRow).appendTo("#Account tbody");


            });
        }
    }
}); 
return values;
};
```

I have written an ajax function where I am passing userID to servlet and retrieving      accountno and accountType. I want to show accountno and account type in jsp page but I couldn't and it is not working. Please help me. Regards,
Ruby

```
<form action="HostingProject/AdminCustServlet" method="post">
  <table id="Account">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>AccountNo</th>
        <th>AccountType</th>                    
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

</tbody>
</table>

public void retrieve(HttpServletRequest request){
     //TODO Retrieve AccountnNo and AccountType
     PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
     SIPAdminCustManager custManager = new SIPAdminCustManager();
     System.out.println("manager in retrieve");
     int userID = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("161"));
     List<String> acclist = custManager.retrieveAccountNamebyID(userID);
     System.out.println("got acclist"+acclist.size());
    Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(acclist);
response.setContentType("Application/json");
response.getWriter().write(json);
System.out.println("json"+json);
}
```

Comment: Can you tell your flow? From your question I am understanding that you have a JSP page, from that page you are taking a userid from user then you are calling the AJAX function by passing that userid to the Servlet. In Servlet you are processing that userid and want to get the information and then you want to show that information in same JSP page.
Am I right?

Comment: Yes,Deepak. I have view.jsp Page where I am showing alluser infoList with edit button.Once the edit button is click it will go to edit.jsp page  then I want to show the list of account that userID  belongs to. Regards,Ruby

Comment: Okay, So where are you getting the problem?

Comment: I am unable to bind data in <c:foreach> tag. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please help me. I am having difficulties to bind with table.

Comment: When AJAX return the value you must process it with Javascript not JSP. So <c:forEach is of no use to you there. JSP stops running when it sends the HTML source to the browser, and its Javascript time from there on out.

Comment: Thank you developerwjk. Would you mind giving me a link where I can find some relevant resources.

Comment: After inserting  contentType: 'application/json' I am getting undefined in my tablerow. Any help can I get to show my string list?

Comment: In this way I am not been able to get data in success: function(data ,textStatus, jqXHR).  From servlet println I can see all my data but it is not passing to jsp ajax success function. Is there a better way to do it? Regards,